# How to fix ''.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Press any key to continue . . .' error in geany?

Tags: java

I'm new to java & I cannot run the code because of an error.

This is for windows 10 & java.

```java
import java.util.*;
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        System.out.print("Input 1st Number:");
        a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input 2nd Number:");
        b=input.nextInt();
        if(a>b){
            int c;
            c=a+b;
            System.out.println(c);
            }else{
            System.out.println(a+" "+b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code. please make sure there is no stray characters in the file.

Comment: What's that error? Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to execute your source as a shell script. You need to compile your code with `javac` then run it with `java`.